# Setting up VPN access over home dsl router?

Tags: vpn, local-area-network, adsl

I have a ADSL connection at home, however it is not static ip address based, and the ip changes every couple of hours. here is how the setup looks like

Internet ------ ADSL Router --------Internal LAN ------Machine 1, Machine 2, Machine 3

Now I want to access the different machines (1,2,3) from somewhere in the Internet in a secure way, maybe using something like a VPN...

any idea how i can set this up?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe start with getting a dynamic hostname.

http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/

Then you can just setup port fowarding on your router to take care of the rest, depending on which services you want to access.

If that's not what you're looking for, see if your router supports DD-WRT and install the VPN flavor.

Comment: I get the DynDns and port forwarding part ... but where do I setup the software based VPN? should it be on one of the machines (1,2,3)?

Comment: I do not have a router which supports DD-WRT.

Comment: What services are you trying to access?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Hamachi2 from LogMeIn, makes this a cinch. Basically one of your machines at home becomes a peer-to-peer gateway. It's a piece of cake, really.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is TeamViewer.